# How can I make an overlay network in docker without using docker-machine commands

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Docker documentation explains how to make an overlay network using the command

```
eval $(docker-machine -swarm master)
docker network create -d overlay test-overlay
```

The problem is thet I am not using docker-machine to setup my cluster. When I try to create an overlay network I get an error.

Command that is executed on my swarm master (listening on port 4000)

```
docker -H :4000 network create -d overlay test-overlay
```

The exception I get when executing the command

```
Error response from daemon: 500 Internal Server Error: failed to parse pool request for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": cannot find address space GlobalDefault (most likely the backing datastore is not configured)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, you need a backing datastore.

- You need to setup at least a key-value store, for example `consul` or `etcd`.
- In case of using `consul`, you need to run your docker daemon with `--cluster-store consul://<your consul ip>:8500 --cluster-advertise eth0:4000`. I assume that you use `eth0` as the network interface for your docker daemon.